# sbt error [scala/tools/nsc/settings/MutableSettings$Setting

Tags: scala, sbt, noclassdeffounderror

I real don't know what to do.
CentOS 7.
All the time any sbt command crash with beginning message,

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
scala/tools/nsc/settings/MutableSettings$Setting
```

For example:

```
    [gdev@gru PROJECTS]$ sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
    [error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/nsc/settings/MutableSettings$Setting
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.CompilerCommand.<init>(CompilerCommand.scala:12)
[error]     at sbt.internal.parser.SbtParser$.defaultGlobalForParser$lzycompute(SbtParser.scala:114)
[error]     at sbt.internal.parser.SbtParser$.defaultGlobalForParser(SbtParser.scala:111)
[error]     at sbt.internal.parser.SbtParser$.parse(SbtParser.scala:153)
[error]     at sbt.internal.parser.SbtParser.splitExpressions(SbtParser.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.parser.SbtParser.<init>(SbtParser.scala:206)

which sbt 
/usr/bin/sbt 

which scala 
/usr/bin/scala 

scala -version 
Scala code runner version 2.12.6 -- Copyright 2002-2018, 
LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc. 

echo $JAVA_HOME 
/opt/jdk1.8.0_181 

sudo yum list sbt 
sbt.noarch 1.2.3-0
```

Comment: I clear system (CentOS 7), reinstall Java and scala (2.11.8) and sbt 1.2.3 but error still exists.

Comment: I try from root and everything good. But, it's no possible to coding from root. Any suggestions please.